# I keep getting "cannot declare parameter '_inputVerifier' to be of abstract type 'InputVerifier'" error

Tags: c++, derived-class, base-class

I'm currently converting a project from Java into C++. I'm using base classes as interface classes and I'm using derived classes as a subclass of the "interface" class. Right now, I'm having an issue regarding base and derived classes. Here's some of the code in the CPP file:

```
enum class State {
    START, INTEGER, DECIMAL, END
};

class Edge {
    private:
        State currentState;
        InputVerifier inputVerifier;
        Action action;
        State nextState;
    public:
        Edge(State _currentState, InputVerifier _inputVerifier, Action _action, State _nextState) {
            currentState = _currentState;
            inputVerifier = _inputVerifier;
            action = _action;
            nextState = _nextState;
        }
};

Edge machine[1] = {
    Edge(State::START, DigitInputVerifier(), ValueIsDigitAction(), State::INTEGER)
};
```

And some of the code in the header file:

```
class InputVerifier {
    public:
        virtual bool meetsCriteria(char c) = 0;
};

class Action {
    public:
        virtual InterimResult execute(InterimResult x, char c) = 0;
};

class ValueIsDigitAction: public virtual Action {
    public:
        InterimResult execute(InterimResult x, char c) override {
            x.setV(c - '0');
            return x;
        }
};

class DigitInputVerifier: public virtual InputVerifier {
    public:
        bool meetsCriteria(char c) override {
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                return true;
            }
        return false;
        }
};
```

InterimResult is another class but that's not an issue. I've been trying to compile this but one of the errors I keep on getting is **error: cannot declare parameter '_inputVerifier' to be of abstract type 'InputVerifier'**. I've been trying to search this issue up but I'm not having much luck. I'm new to using classes in C++ so I'm trying to learn but I don't understand how to fix this error. If you could, could you explain what a pure virtual function is too? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error explicitly shows you the error: the class  `InputVerifier` is abstract because of the  `virtual bool meetsCriteria(char c) = 0;` abstract method. You cannot create instances of this class.

Comment: `InputVerifier` is an abstract class because it has pure virtual function. You cannot create an object of it. You could have pointer `InputVerifier*` as member and can pass any child class object that implements the virtual functions though. In this case `DigitInputVerifier`

Comment: Just to be clear, what I'm trying to achieve is a sort of superclass and subclass relation where I have one superclass and I can have many subclasses. The superclass variable will be assigned to whatever subclass I want to assign to it.
Also, when I try to make the variable a pointer, I get "undefined reference to WinMain@16", which apparently means the application is trying to create a windows application rather than a console application.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not Java. Obviously. One of the consequences is that the parameters could be passed either by value or by reference. Regarding `InputVerifier` that means that:

- The `InputVerifier inputVerifier` is an attempt to create an instance of the class `InputVerifier` (and this class is abstract, so no instances are allowed).
- The parameter `InputVerifier _inputVerifier` is passed by value, so again: this is an attempt to create a class that cannot be created.
- There is an attempt of a deep copy `inputVerifier = _inputVerifier;`
- When you pass the `DigitInputVerifier()` argument, you actually create a temporary object (it will be destroyed right after the expression is evaluated), and that this value is being copied to be passed by value.

The same applies to `Action`.

What you might want is:

```cpp
class Edge {
    private:
        State currentState;
        InputVerifier &inputVerifier;
        Action &action;
        State nextState;
    public:
        Edge(State _currentState, InputVerifier &_inputVerifier, Action &_action, State _nextState)
            : currentState(_currentState),
              inputVerifier(_inputVerifier),
              action(_action),
              nextState(_nextState) {
        }
};

DigitInputVerifier digitInputVerifier;
ValueIsDigitAction valueIsDigitAction;
Edge machine[1] = {
    Edge(State::START, digitInputVerifier, valueIsDigitAction, State::INTEGER)
};
```

One more thing: `public virtual` is a special type of inheritance, and I guess that you don't need it. Simple `class DigitInputVerifier: public InputVerifier` would be enough.

Comment: So I've implemented that but I got this error: "undefined reference to `WinMain@16'". Help?

Comment: You need to define the `main` function (or WinMain, depends on the platform). I would advise you to study the basics of C++ and the simple Windows app example from MSVC.